# solr :cannot delete a document using post

Tags: solr

I'm newbie to solr, I'm trying to test different possibilities to delete a document.
I have tested the
`update?commit=true&stream.body=<delete><query>*:*</query></delete>`.

An other method that I find from [solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/quickstart.html) quick start said that a document can be deleted
 using :  `bin/post -c gettingstarted -d "<delete><id>SP2514N</id></delete>"`

When I try it seems that it works, but when I search for the id I find it.

why it doesn't work, and I wonder if there is other ways to delete a document (for example using the admin console).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/gettingstarted/update?stream.body=<delete><query>id:SP2514N</query></delete>&commit=true
```

check [Here](http://blog.dileno.com/archive/201106/delete-documents-from-solr-index-by-query/) for reference

Comment: yeah I already tried it and it works, but now I'm trying to test other possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you issued a commit after you deleted (hence the `commit=true` in the URL deletion). Add a `<commit/>` after your delete and that should work. (see more on [Solr Update XML here](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages))

Comment: thank you for respond, I tried to add the `<commit/>` at the end of  `</delete>` but I get a syntax error message.